Is it possible to add an eventListener to a custom title bar used for dragging the window in a frameless window?
Added a custom title bar to a frameless window in order to make the window draggable. The title bar shows, but eventListener won't fire:
main.js:
const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      frame: false,
      scrollbar: false,
      webPreferences:{
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
      }
    })
    win.loadFile('index.html')
  }

index.html:
<body>
  <div class="window">
    <div class="window-content">
      <textarea>some content</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

index.js:
let titleBar = document.createElement('div')
titleBar.style.width = "100%"
titleBar.style.height = "32px"
titleBar.style.backgroundColor = "#fff"
titleBar.style.position = "absolute"
titleBar.style.top = titleBar.style.left = 0
titleBar.style.webkitAppRegion = "drag"
titleBar.textContent = 'My App';

document.body.appendChild(titleBar)

// Nothing happens
titleBar.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    console.log("hello")
})


You don't need to use eventListener, you can achieve this use only CSS.
main.js
const createWindow = () => {
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  frame: false,
  scrollbar: false,
  titleBarStyle: 'hidden',//Add this
  titleBarOverlay: {
   color: '#ecf2f9',
   symbolColor: '#003d99',
   height: 40,
  },//Add this for windows
  webPreferences:{
    nodeIntegration: true,
    contextIsolation: false,
  }
})
win.loadFile('index.html')
}

index.html
 <body>
<div class="titleBar">
My App
</div>
<div class="window">
  <div class="window-content">
    <textarea>some content</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="index.js"></script>

index.css
.titleBar{
background-color: #ecf2f9;
height: 40px; /* Adjust height as needed */
-webkit-app-region: drag; /*Allow dragging the window */
.
.
.
}


Many thanks for showing an alternative way of creating a custom title bar. This however also does not allow any eventListeners to be detected. So like @oOosys says, with a draggable title bar, eventListeners don't seem to be possible.
